# What steps are needed to create dynamic PHP pages based on MySQL criteria?

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic

I have a large library of folk music which is organized by "collection" (ID and name) in the MYSQL database.

I have an html5 player in the root directory which is set up to add **all** tracks in the "track" table to the playlist. Each track in the "track" table includes collection IDs from the "collection" table.

What I want: A user can go to:

```
www.site-title.com/player/pID=1 //(or something like that)
```

And the playlist will only evaluate tracks where collection_id=1

Can you explain how this would be developed logically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Run database query
2. Fetch results
3. Use results to build page
4. Send page to user

Comment: Great. Thanks! So for steps 1 and 2 I would use a SQL SELECT statement, for step 3 I would use a PHP function like rawurlencode, and for step 4 I would just populate the page with the data from the SQL query?

Comment: rawurlencode is for building urls, not pages. you'd only use it if you're embedding one url in another, or a url has url-metacharcters you need "escaped".

Comment: Can you recommend a PHP function to build the URL?

Comment: Why? a url is just some text. `<a href="yourscript.php?albumID=<?php echo $albumID ?>">` works just fine.